# genhtml: ERROR: cannot read path-to-file on Linux only

Tags: linux, code-coverage, gcov, lcov

I generate lcov file and use genhtml to produce html report files using:

```
genhtml out/cov.info -o out/temp
```

On windows it works fine and the index.html is generated, while in Linux I get this error:

```
Found 1 entries.
Found common filename prefix "/absolute/path/files/data"
Writing .css and .png files.
Generating output.
Processing file file/file.py
genhtml: ERROR: cannot read /absolute/path/files/file.py
```

I checked the presence of this file /absolute/path/files/file.py
I applied chmod 777 on this file, still have this error.
Also in the cov.info file the source file SF:/absolute/path/files/file.py is correct and has valid records.

Answer (score 0):

Gcov will throw these errors if the compilation timestamp of gcno files are different than the binary used to execute the Test case. To simplify this, whenever your binary is compiled, update these files and then re-run . It should work